# node js sql modules able to output json responses from an sql database

Tags: sql, json, node.js, postgresql

i'm looking for node modules to connect with my postgresql database.

Also, in order to keep code good enough to understand and maintain, i need something more.

My research gave me a few options:

- https://github.com/brianc/node-sql
- https://github.com/C2FO/patio
- https://github.com/hiddentao/squel
- https://github.com/on-point/thin-orm

My main needs are:

1. To be able to either avoid query string concats or load external queries
2. Receive or automatically transform the query result into json (so my express controller can answer my angular frontend)
3. Avoid as much as possible any performance issue

I'll thank and take a good look on any recommendation, and will update this thread to share my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend for PostgreSQL **BookShelf** (http://bookshelfjs.org/), it's based on the **Knex** Query Builder (http://knexjs.org/)

Comment: thanks a lot, i'm using knex and the migrations thing to manage my postgre database. it's quite neat.